# Add new date row in jsp page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to add new row in a jsp page, upon clicking on a hyperlink.

Its working fine but in the new row, date function `class="dateTxt"` is not working. Below is the jsp and javascript function details.

javascript:

```
function addNewRow(addingNewRow){

    var table = document.getElementById("addingNewRow");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    cell1.innerHTML = cell1.innerHTML + '<td><input type="number" value="" size="10"></td>';
    cell2.innerHTML = cell2.innerHTML + '<td><input type="number" value="" size="10"></td>';
    cell3.innerHTML = cell3.innerHTML + '<td><input type="number" value="" size="10"></td>';
    cell4.innerHTML = cell4.innerHTML + '<td><input type="number" value="" size="10"></td>';
    cell5.innerHTML = cell5.innerHTML + '<td><input id="effDate3" class="dateTxt" type="text" ></td>';
    cell6.innerHTML = cell6.innerHTML + '<td><input id="discDate3" class="dateTxt" type="text" ></td>';
    cell7.innerHTML = cell7.innerHTML + '<td><select id="action" name="actionId"><option value="-1" selected="selected">--Select One--</option><option value="0" >Add</option><option value="1" >Edit</option><option value="2" >Delete</option></select></td>';
}
```

Date function:

```
$(function(){$('.dateTxt').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}); });
```

Jsp:

```
href="#" onclick="addNewRow('addingNewRow')">Add More Parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the datepicker for the new row. Execute this line

```
$(function(){$('.dateTxt').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'}); });
```

at the end of your `addNewRow()` function. This will work, but also you should read about `jquery.on()` to bind events to dynamic childs.

Comment: But i had defined that function already under script tag. Why it was not picking from there.

Comment: because the new row not exists in the DOM when you initialize the plugin. You need to 'propagate' the event to the new elements you append at the DOM.